# Using Jquery Functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, telerik

**Completely revised for clarity and simplicity**

I am using elevate zoom (Lens Zoom Feature) as shown on [on this website](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#gallery-lightbox). I have a Radrotator filled with Binary Images that I have given an onclick event on DataBound of the rotator. Onclick I want to change the Main much larger image above the Rotator based on the image they clicked on from the Rotator all client side.

The image on the screen does in fact change, however, the magnify feature still shows the first image.

```
<img id="zoom_07" runat="server" src="small.jpg" alt="image" />
```

Below are the two javascript functions. The first is using elevatezoom to magnify the image while the second is being called onclick of the Binary images in the rotator.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#zoom_07").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "lens",
        lensShape: "round",
        lensSize: 200
    });
});

function changeImage(url) {

    var img = document.getElementById('zoom_07');
    img.src = url;
    img.setAttribute('data-zoom-image', url);
}
```

How can I change the image in the magnifier client side?  Thank you for any help on this matter.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, you say 'How can I call this jquery function in a JAVASCRIPT function?' It's not clear what jQuery function you are referring to. Of the code you showed, there is nothing special there that I see, unless something is left out. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/ section under 'Aliasing the jQuery namespace'. All that your ready function is doing is converting your jQuery variable to be aliased to $ in your handler method. If you took the code from the ready function and replaced $ with jQuery it should work in your javascript function.

Comment: What i am hoping to do is call the $("#zoom_07").elevateZoom inside the changeImage function b/c the data-zoom-image image is not correctly changing as the img.src image did change. I edited my question above a bit. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Based on your NEW description someone else had this issue and got the latest version: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/q/discussion/5/rotatingsliding-images-zoom-on-the-container-div - otherwise, I think I would recommend you post a question to that sites help desk; - Likely no-one here will have a desire to debug someone elses plug-in code.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I believe you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the solution](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo3) I went with. I created image tags in the rotator (which is bound to binary images) and changed the main image on click of those images. I of course had to convert the binary images to regular images and then save them.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery **is** JavaScript so you're already calling it in a JavaScript function. it just happens to be an anonymous function on *document ready*.

```
function changeImage(url) {
    var img = document.getElementById('zoom_07');
    img.src = url;
    img.setAttribute('data-zoom-image', url);

    $(img).elevatedZoom({
        zoomType: "lens",
        lensShape: "round",
        lensSize: 200
    });
}
```

The above code is your event handler that has been updated to show you were you would want to call the function to update the zoom.

Comment: The data-zoom-image is still not updating correctly. I thought this would be the fix.

Comment: I do an alert after I set the data-zoom-image url and the attribute is actually changing, but it is not changing for the user. The magnifying glass will only show the previous magnified image, while the image defined in img.src does actually change.

Answer (score 0):

I made some wide assumptions on what you are clicking and the source of the url here:

```
(function ($) {
    // I invented this, use your element
    $('#clickemeid').click(function () { 
        // I invented this "someattr" attribute, set to where you get that
        var url = $(this).attr('someattr');
        $("#zoom_07").attr('src', url).attr('data-zoom-image', url).elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "lens",
            lensShape: "round",
            lensSize: 200
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

NOW, making the assumption you want to toggle between the src and data-zoom-image

```
(function ($) {
    $('#zoom_07').click(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        var zoomurl = me.attr('data-zoom-image');
        var origurl = me.attr('src');
        me.attr('data-zoom-image', origurl).attr('src', zoomurl).elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "lens",
            lensShape: "round",
            lensSize: 200
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Neither of these worked. Please see my revised question as I attempted to make it a bit more clear.